# Changing QGIS Python Plugin Directory

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I work in an environment where both the program files for QGIS as well as the connection to the Plugin repository are blocked. Is there a way that I can point QGIS to look in an alternative directory for python plugins. I can see that this is possible for C++ plugins but fail to see an option for Python ones.

Comment: This is different in QGIS2 und QGIS3 and it depends on which OS your are. Please tell us!

Comment: I'm working on QGIS 2.18 and on windows - sorry for not clarifying earlier!

Answer (score 3):

There is an start option for QGIS called configpath. You can change it by editing the batch file in the bin directory, which calls qgis. The last line should look like this:

```
start "QGIS" /B "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\qgis-ltr-bin.exe --configpath %HOME%\.qgis2 %*
```

If you don't have write access to the directory (normally C:\OSGeo4W\bin) you should be able to copy the batch file to your user directory. Because it is important to execute `o4w_env.bat`, the second line must be changed also and include the absolute path to `o4w_env.bat`, e.g.

```
call "C:\OSGeo4W\bin\o4w_env.bat"
```

Please make sure, you change it to the path on your system.

If you want to inform the system adminstrator about your issue, there is a blog article about installing QGIS on a Windows share: http://www.qgis.nl/2014/04/22/qgis-in-de-klas-onder-windows/?lang=en

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! Unfortunately, as the program files are blocked I can't access this (option?). Were I able to, where would I actually change the directory for the python plugins? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by being blocked? How can you start qgis without read access?

Comment: The directories are blocked in Windows explorer and don't have access to the command prompt either. Managed to sort this issue in the end by setting up a local plugin repository.